# How to merge two tables of csv by comparing the similarities of the string inside

Tags: python, pandas, csv, machine-learning, merge

I want to merge two DF into one by comparing the similarity of the string using levenshtein from fuzzy-wuzzy package. I need to remove symbols or spaces in between the strings. If DF1 doesn't match any data from DF2 it remains in the table as it is and vice versa. I did something simple like this:

```
 from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz

# Define the two input DataFrames
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'name': ['John', 'Anna', 'Mike', 'Samantha'],
    'age': [25, 32, 18, 45]
})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'username': ['j0hn_d03', 'anna_jones', 'mike_smith', 'sam_567'],
    'age': [28, 30, 20, 43]
})

# Remove symbols and spaces in the name and username columns
df1['name'] = df1['name'].str.replace(r'\W', '').str.lower()
df2['username'] = df2['username'].str.replace(r'\W', '').str.lower()

# Create an empty DataFrame to store the merged results
merged_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['name', 'age', 'username', 'match_ratio'])

# Loop over the rows of the first DataFrame and compare them to the second DataFrame
for i, row1 in df1.iterrows():
    best_match = None
    best_ratio = 0
    for j, row2 in df2.iterrows():
        ratio = fuzz.ratio(row1['name'], row2['username'])
        if ratio > best_ratio:
            best_ratio = ratio
            best_match = row2
    if best_match is not None:
        merged_df = merged_df.append({
            'name': row1['name'],
            'age': row1['age'],
            'username': best_match['username'],
            'match_ratio': best_ratio
        }, ignore_index=True)
    else:
        merged_df = merged_df.append({
            'name': row1['name'],
            'age': row1['age'],
            'username': None,
            'match_ratio': 0
        }, ignore_index=True)

# Loop over the rows of the second DataFrame and add the non-matching rows to the merged DataFrame
for i, row2 in df2.iterrows():
    if not merged_df['username'].str.contains(row2['username']).any():
        merged_df = merged_df.append({
            'name': None,
            'age': row2['age'],
            'username': row2['username'],
            'match_ratio': 0
        }, ignore_index=True)

# Convert the match_ratio column to integers and sort the merged DataFrame by age
merged_df['match_ratio'] = merged_df['match_ratio'].astype(int)
merged_df = merged_df.sort_values(by='age').reset_index(drop=True)
```

But I have 1000 different names so I cannot check the errors manually and I also have other characteristics to help with the classification. Is it possible to use machine learning to improve the accuracy or any other way to let the data more understandable to Python to differentiate?

Edit: What I meant is, there are many John in my 'name' column and some of them meant different people but some are the same just different entries with different characteristics. Like name: 'John', age: 25, bag_colour: 'Black', the other one, username: 'j0hn_d01', age: 25, bag_colour: 'Blue'.In this case, there should be two John in my merged csv as it is illogical for the same student to have two bags. So Python should be based on all the characteristics combined instead of just one column.

Answer (score 0):

I would do a full outer merge, then use lambda to more cleanly check each row.

```
df3 = pd.merge(df1.assign(key=1), df2.assign(key=1), on='key').drop('key', axis=1)
df3['match_ratio'] = df3.apply(lambda x: fuzz.ratio(x['name'], x['username']), axis=1)

print(df3)
        name  age_x    username  age_y  match_ratio
0       John     25    j0hn_d03     28           33
1       John     25  anna_jones     30           29
2       John     25  mike_smith     20           14
3       John     25     sam_567     43            0
4       Anna     32    j0hn_d03     28           17
5       Anna     32  anna_jones     30           43
6       Anna     32  mike_smith     20            0
7       Anna     32     sam_567     43           18
8       Mike     18    j0hn_d03     28            0
9       Mike     18  anna_jones     30           14
10      Mike     18  mike_smith     20           43
11      Mike     18     sam_567     43            0
12  Samantha     45    j0hn_d03     28           12
13  Samantha     45  anna_jones     30           33
14  Samantha     45  mike_smith     20           33
15  Samantha     45     sam_567     43           27
```

From here you can drop or keep rows as needed, based on match_ratio, age, or any other criteria